# Any way to specify preferred mime types?

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there any way to specify a preferred mime type? For example, my service accepts both HTML and Word files. If it's coming from Google Docs, I'd like to use their native conversion (i.e. I prefer to get HTML files). However, I'd also like to be able to pick word files off of dropbox (which I will convert locally). If I specify both in mimetypes, it always gives me a word file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature does not exist, but I have filed a ticket. What we will likely do is treat the array of mimetypes preferentially, that is ['text/html', 'application/msword'] will return the html document, whereas ['application/msword', 'text/html'] will give you the word doc. I will update this when we make progress